# Splitting Uint16 into Uint8

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function which take a Uint16 and splits it into 2 Uint8 values
Right now i'm getting values in the variables but these aren't the right ones. I don't know what goes wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: so after Joachim Sauer suggestions I changed the code. it works better but still not the right values

*Javascript Code*

```
let reg1;
let reg2;
let input;
function int16ToInt8(){
    input = document.getElementById("reg").value;
    reg1 = input;
    reg2 = input >> 8;
}
```

Comment: On what basis do you want he split? First and last bits?

Comment: The loops are pointless, you ignore the `id` parameter and using global variables for return values is a very dangerous idea.

Comment: how can i use the id parameter? if i try to used it it gives a null value error.
And I want it split so that i can put it in a dataview, I send it through bluetooth so that the other side can recombine it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct you want `reg1` to contain the less significative byte and `reg2` the most significative one. If so, you need to mask `reg1` like this:

```
reg1 = Number(input) & 0xff;
```